# Error while starting HCK studio on server 2008 r2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

When I try to open HCK studio, it shows an error:

```
Error: Failed to connect to database. Failed to connect to OM.
```

I tried the solution mentioned here:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/0371abd0-9d9b-427d-95b1-8a57ee69b50a/error-failed-to-connect-to-database-failed-to-connect-to-om?forum=whck

It did not solve my problem.

Under HCK Manager ->Tools -> Management Console   ->
**"Datastore"** is missing in my case. How to create new one (if possible)? and I don't know which user had installed HCK on server pc.

And any one can tell me the Server role required for driver testing on SQL Server manager? ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Database name cannot be greater then 15 characters.

If your controller name is greater then 15 characters you must be facing the same problem as mine.